# Как удалить из ArrayList элементы, относящиеся к определенному классу?

Tags: java, массивы, коллекции

Есть родительский класс `Commodity`, от него наследуются классы `Flower` и `Accessory`.
В коде создается `ArrayList<Commodity>`, куда добавляются объекты обоих дочерних классов.

В одном из методов необходимо отсортировать все значения класса `Flower` из `ArrayList`. Моя идея - создать новый `ArrayList<Flower>` взяв за основу исходный `ArrayList`, из которого удалить все объекты класса `Accessory`.

Вот тут и встает вопрос - как удалить из `ArrayList<Commodity>` все элементы класса `Accessory`? Я пробую через метод `removeif()`, добавив в него некий фильтр - тут и застопорился процесс:

```java
ArrayList<Flower> bouquetListFlowersOnly = new ArrayList<>();
bouquetListFlowersOnly = bouquetList.removeIf(n -> (n.isInstance(Accessory)));
```

*n.isInstance(Accessory) - пример неудачного решения*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`removeIf` не возвращает новую коллекцию, `removeIf` удаляет из текущей коллекции и возвращает `true`, если был удалён хотя бы один элемент. А проверка на тип производится оператором `instanceof`: `n instanceof Accessory`

То, что вам надо проще всего сделать через `Stream`:

```
List<Flower> bouquetListFlowersOnly = bouquetList.stream().filter(n -> n instanceof Flower).sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
```